# Limit Multple User in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multiple roles in my laravel-app like `admin`, `sale-manager`, `saleman`. I want to limit `sale data` between `sale-man` except `admin` and `sale-manager`.

**`In my SaleController`**

```
$query = Sale::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                    ->with(['member'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Its work for only `user` who create `sale`. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add control user role then you should run query according this. For example code block,

```
if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
         $query = Sale::with(['member'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    } else {
         $query = Sale::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                        ->with(['member'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

I hope it works.